# Laravel Queue not able to convert class object to string

Tags: laravel-5, queue

The Issue is when I pass long encoded string as parameter to create object of a class I get error here is my code below:-

```
 $job=new ReProcessShipment("PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz4KPFJlcXVlc3Q+
        CiAgPFRyYW5zSWQ+NjU3MTA8L1RyYW5zSWQ+CiAgPEFjY291bnRJZD5NWUdPPC9B
        Y2NvdW50................."); //8477 charter long encoded string
         ReProcessShipment::dispatch($job);
```

ReProcessShipment Class handle function

```
$request_data['request_data'] =  $this->data_get;
        $request_data['service'] ='shipment_order_relay';
        $webservice_data = Webservice::create($request_data);

        try {
            $value = urldecode($this->data_get);
            $value = base64_decode($value);
            $value = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $value);
            $result = $this->insert_stg_shipment($value, $webservice_data->id);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $value = base64_decode($this->data_get);
            $value = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $value);
            $result = $this->insert_stg_shipment($value, $webservice_data->id);
        }
```

in Logs I get error:

> Object of class App\Jobs\ReProcessShipment could not be converted to
>   string  {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0):  Object of
>   class App\Jobs\ReProcessShipment could not be converted to string at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried implementing a [__toString()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) function for the ReProcessShipment object ?

The string cast seems to be the cause of the error and __toString should allow a correct conversion by returning the string version of your object that you have chosen.

Comment: the able is just an example of implementation but laravel internally call it while saving class object in table

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get that. Is the error not produced by the "return (string)$job;" ?

Comment: No laravel queue `ReProcessShipment::dispatch($job);` this is generating error